# Datatable api.draw is not woking. How can i define the columns and render each row?

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

Currently appending each row, but without the draw method pagination doesn't show. How can the column be defined and with the defined column need to render rows. What am I doing wrong here ?

//ignore this repeated section .
Currently appending each row, but without the draw method pagination doesn't show. How can the column be defined and with the defined column need to render rows. What am I doing wrong here ?

javascript:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    var loading_image_src = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'project_base_assets/base_demo_images/loading.gif';
    var loading_image = '<img src="' + loading_image_src + ' ">';
    var loading_span = '<span><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> ';
    var loading_text = "<div style='font-size:larger' ><?php echo lang('loading_text')?></div>";

    $('#user-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "language": {
            processing: loading_image + '<br>' + loading_text
        },

        'columnDefs': [{
            // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
            // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
            // this case `data: 0`.
            "render": function (data, type, row) {

                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(type);
                console.log(row);

                return data;
            },
            "targets": 0
        }, {orderable: false, targets: [3, 7]}/*, { visible: false, targets: [3,4,5] }*/
        ],

        "aaSorting": [[5, 'asc']],

        "ajax": {
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'users/auth/get_users_by_ajax' ?>",                    // json datasource
            type: "post",
            success: function (res) {

                $('#user-table-tbody').children("tr").remove();

                console.log(res.last_query);
                 console.log(res.common_filter_value);
                 console.log(res.specific_filters);
                 console.log(res.order_column);
                 console.log(res.order_by);
                 console.log(res.limit_start);
                 console.log(res.limit_length);

                $('#user-table_processing').css('display', 'block');

                for (var i = 0; i < res.data.users.length; i++) {

                    var col = new Array();
                    col[0] = '<td>' + res.data.users[i].first_name + '</td>';
                    col[1] = '<td>' + res.data.users[i].last_name + '</td>';
                    col[2] = '<td title="' + res.data.users[i].email + '" >' + res.data.users[i].email + '</td>';

                    //col-3 starts
                    var group_names = '';
                    for (var incr = 0; incr < res.data.users[i].groups.length; incr++) {
                        group_names += res.data.users[i].groups[incr].name;

                        group_names += '<br>';
                    }
                    col[3] = '<td>' + group_names + '</td>';
                    //col-3 ends

                    //col-4 starts
                    var status_span = '';
                    var status_anchor = '';
                    var status_anchor_span = '';
                    var tooltip_deactivate_text = '<?php echo lang('tooltip_deactivate_text') ?>';
                    var tooltip_activate_text = '<?php echo lang('tooltip_activate_text') ?>';
                    var deactivate_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'users/auth/deactivateUser/' + res.data.users[i].id;
                    var activate_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'users/auth/activateUser/' + res.data.users[i].id;
                    col[4] = '';

                    if (res.data.users[i].active == 1) {
                        status_span = '<span class="label label-primary">' + '<?php echo lang('status_active_text')?>' + '</span>';
                        status_anchor_span = '<span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
                        status_anchor = '<a title="' + tooltip_deactivate_text + '" ' + ' href="' + deactivate_url + '" ' + '>' + status_anchor_span + '</a>';
                        col[4] = '<td data-sort="' + res.data.users[i].active + '"> ' + status_span + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + status_anchor + '</td>';
                    } else {
                        status_span = '<span class="label label-primary">' + '<?php echo lang('status_inactive_text')?>' + '</span>';
                        status_anchor_span = '<span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
                        status_anchor = '<a title="' + tooltip_activate_text + '" ' + ' href="' + activate_url + '" ' + '>' + status_anchor_span + '</a>';
                        col[4] = '<td data-sort="' + res.data.users[i].active + '"> ' + status_span + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + status_anchor + '</td>';
                    }

                    //col[4] = '<td>' + res.data.users[i].active + '</td>';
                    //col-4 ends

                    col[5] = '<td data-sort="' + res.data.users[i].created_on_timestamp + '" >' + res.data.users[i].created_on + '</td>';
                    col[6] = '<td data-sort="' + res.data.users[i].last_login_timestamp + '" >' + res.data.users[i].last_login + '</td>';

                    //col=7 starts
                    var tooltip_view_text = '<?php echo lang('tooltip_view_text') ?>';
                    var view_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'user_profile_module/user_profile_overview/' + res.data.users[i].id;
                    var view_anchor = '<a title="' + tooltip_view_text + '" ' + ' href="' + view_url + '" '+'style="color:#2b2b2b"' + '>' + '<i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg " aria-hidden="true"></i>' + '</a>';

                    //message unavailable
                    var tooltip_message_text = '<?php echo lang('tooltip_message_text') ?>';
                    var message_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
                    var message_anchor = '<a title="' + tooltip_message_text + '" ' + ' href="' + message_url + '" '+'style="color:#2b2b2b"' + '>' + '<i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + '</a>';

                    var tooltip_edit_text = '<?php echo lang('tooltip_edit_text') ?>';
                    var edit_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+'users/auth/edit_user/'+ res.data.users[i].id;
                    var edit_anchor = '<a title="' + tooltip_edit_text + '" ' + ' href="' + edit_url + '" '+'style="color:#2b2b2b"' + '>' + '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + '</a>';

                    var tooltip_delete_text = '<?php echo lang('tooltip_delete_text') ?>';
                    var delete_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+'users/auth/deleteUser/'+res.data.users[i].id;
                    var delete_anchor = '<a class="confirmation" title="' + tooltip_delete_text + '" ' + ' href="' + delete_url + '" '+'style="color:#2b2b2b"' + '>' + '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + '</a>';

                    col[7] = '<td>' + view_anchor+'&nbsp; &nbsp;'+edit_anchor+'&nbsp; &nbsp;'+delete_anchor+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</td>';
                    //col-7 ends

                    var row = '<tr>';

                    for (var inc = 0; inc < col.length; inc++) {

                        row += col[inc];
                    }

                    row += '</tr>';


                    //console.log(row);
                    $('#user-table-tbody').append(row);


                }

                //hide loading after appending or drawing rows
                $('#user-table_processing').css('display', 'none');

            }
        }

    }).draw();
});
```

php:

```
public function getUsersByAjax()
{
    $requestData = $_REQUEST;

    $columns[0] = 'first_name';
    $columns[1] = 'last_name';
    $columns[2] = 'email';
    $columns[3] = 'group';
    $columns[4] = 'active';
    $columns[5] = 'created_on';
    $columns[6] = 'last_login';
    $columns[7] = 'actions';

    $common_filter_value = false;
    $order_column = false;

    $specific_filters = array();
    //$specific_filters = false;

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['first_name'] = $requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['last_name'] = $requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['email'] = $requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['group'] = $requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['active'] = $requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value'];
    }


    if (!empty($requestData['search']['value'])) {
        $common_filter_value = $requestData['search']['value'];
    }

    if ($specific_filters == true || !empty($specific_filters)) {
        $common_filter_value = false;       //either search with specific filters or with common filter
    }

    $order['column'] = $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']];
    $order['by'] = $requestData['order'][0]['dir'];


    $limit['start'] = $requestData['start'];
    $limit['length'] = $requestData['length'];

    $totalData = $this->Custom_auth_model->countUsers($common_filter_value, $specific_filters);

    if ($common_filter_value == true || $specific_filters == true) {
        $totalFiltered = $totalData;
    } else {
        $totalFiltered = $this->Custom_auth_model->countUsers($common_filter_value = false, $specific_filters = false);
    }

    $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.

    $data['users'] = $this->Custom_auth_model->getUsers($common_filter_value, $specific_filters,$order,$limit);
    $last_query = $this->db->last_query();

    foreach ($data['users'] as $k => $user) {
        $data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();

    }

    $this->load->library('custom_datetime_library');


    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data['users'] as $a_user) {

        $data['users'][$i]->created_on_timestamp = $a_user->created_on;
        $data['users'][$i]->last_login_timestamp = $a_user->last_login;

        if ($a_user->created_on == 0) {
            $a_user->created_on = $this->lang->line('creation_time_unknown_text');
        } else {
            $a_user->created_on =
                $this->custom_datetime_library
                    ->convert_and_return_TimestampToDateAndTime($a_user->created_on);
        }

        if ($a_user->last_login == 0) {
            $a_user->last_login = $this->lang->line('never_logged_in_text');
        } else {
            $a_user->last_login =
                $this->custom_datetime_library
                    ->convert_and_return_TimestampToDateAndTime($a_user->last_login);
        }

        $i++;

    }

    $json_data['draw'] = intval($requestData['draw']);

    /* $totalData: for every request/draw by clientside ,
     they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number,
     so we are sending same number in draw.*/
    $json_data['recordsTotal'] = intval($totalData); // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
    $json_data['recordsFiltered'] = intval($totalFiltered);

    $json_data['data'] = $data;

    // checking requests in console.log();
    $json_data['last_query'] = $last_query;
    $json_data['common_filter_value'] = $common_filter_value;
    $json_data['specific_filters'] = $specific_filters;
    $json_data['order_column'] = $order['column'];
    $json_data['order_by'] = $order['by'];
    $json_data['limit_length'] = $limit['length'];
    $json_data['limit_start'] = $limit['start'];


    echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not using the API correctly. You don't need to build the table manually, so that `for` loop where you append to the table is unnecessary. There are a million examples of using PHP and datatables - [here's](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/) a random one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution 3 Days ago. Have to remove success(){} from Ajax request . It creates problem with the table rendering.Either have to pass data with numerical index or have to use 'orthogonal data method'. Here it is:

Php:

```
public function getUsersByAjax()
{
    $users = array();

    $requestData = $_REQUEST;
    //print_r($requestData);

    $columns[0] = 'first_name';
    $columns[1] = 'last_name';
    $columns[2] = 'email';
    $columns[3] = 'group';
    $columns[4] = 'active';
    $columns[5] = 'created_on';
    $columns[6] = 'last_login';
    $columns[7] = 'actions';

    $common_filter_value = false;
    $order_column = false;

    $specific_filters = array();
    $specific_filters = false;

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['first_name'] = $requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['last_name'] = $requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['email'] = $requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['group'] = $requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value'];
    }

    if (!empty($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value'])) {
        $specific_filters['active'] = $requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value'];
    }


    if (!empty($requestData['search']['value'])) {
        $common_filter_value = $requestData['search']['value'];
    }

    if ($specific_filters == true || !empty($specific_filters)) {
        $common_filter_value = false;       //either search with specific filters or with common filter
    }

    $order['column'] = $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']];
    $order['by'] = $requestData['order'][0]['dir'];


    $limit['start'] = $requestData['start'];
    $limit['length'] = $requestData['length'];

    $totalData = $this->Custom_auth_model->countUsers(false, false);

    if ($common_filter_value == true || $specific_filters == true) {

        $totalFiltered = $this->Custom_auth_model->countUsers($common_filter_value, $specific_filters);
    } else {
        $totalFiltered = $totalData; // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.
    }


    $users = $this->Custom_auth_model->getUsers($common_filter_value, $specific_filters, $order, $limit);

    if ($users == false || empty($users) || $users == null) {
        $users = false;
    }

    $last_query = $this->db->last_query();

    if ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $k => $user) {
            $user_groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
            $users[$k]->groups = '';

            $iter = 0;
            foreach ($user_groups as $a_group) {

                if ($iter != 0) {
                    $users[$k]->groups .= '<br>';
                }

                $users[$k]->groups .= $a_group->name;

                $iter++;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->load->library('custom_datetime_library');


    if ($users) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($users as $a_user) {

            /*date time starts*/
            $users[$i]->cr_on = new stdClass();
            $users[$i]->lt_lg_in = new stdClass();

            $users[$i]->cr_on->timestamp = $a_user->created_on;
            $users[$i]->lt_lg_in->timestamp = $a_user->last_login;

            if ($a_user->created_on == 0) {
                $users[$i]->cr_on->display = $this->lang->line('creation_time_unknown_text');
            } else {
                $users[$i]->cr_on->display =
                    $this->custom_datetime_library
                        ->convert_and_return_TimestampToDateAndTime($a_user->created_on);
            }

            if ($a_user->last_login == 0) {
                $users[$i]->lt_lg_in->display = $this->lang->line('never_logged_in_text');
            } else {
                $users[$i]->lt_lg_in->display =
                    $this->custom_datetime_library
                        ->convert_and_return_TimestampToDateAndTime($a_user->last_login);
            }
            /*date time ends*/

            /*active - inactive starts*/
            $users[$i]->act = new stdClass();
            $users[$i]->act->int = $a_user->active;

            if ($a_user->active == 1) {

                $status_span = '<span class = "label label-primary">' . $this->lang->line('status_active_text') . '</span>';

                $status_tooltip = $this->lang->line('tooltip_deactivate_text');
                $status_url = base_url() . 'users/auth/deactivateUser/' . $a_user->id;
                $status_anchor_span = '<span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
                $status_anchor =
                    '<a ' . ' title="' . $status_tooltip . '"' . ' href="' . $status_url . '">' . $status_anchor_span . '</a>';

            } else {
                $status_span = '<span class = "label label-default">' . $this->lang->line('status_inactive_text') . '</span>';

                $status_tooltip = $this->lang->line('tooltip_activate_text');
                $status_url = base_url() . 'users/auth/activateUser/' . $a_user->id;
                $status_anchor_span = '<span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
                $status_anchor =
                    '<a ' . ' title="' . $this->lang->line('tooltip_activate_text') . '"' . ' href="' . $status_url . '">' . $status_anchor_span . '</a>';
            }

            $users[$i]->act->html = $status_span . '&nbsp; &nbsp;' . $status_anchor;
            /*active - inactive ends*/

            /*action starts*/


            $view_tooltip = $this->lang->line('tooltip_view_text');
            $view_url = base_url() . 'user_profile_module/user_profile_overview/' . $a_user->id;
            $view_anchor =
                '<a ' . ' title="' . $view_tooltip . '" ' . ' href="' . $view_url . '" ' . ' style="color:#2b2b2b" ' . '>'
                . '<i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
                . '</a>';

            $message_tooltip = $this->lang->line('tooltip_message_text');
            $message_url = base_url() . 'message' . $a_user->id; //undefined
            $message_anchor = '<a ' . ' title="' . $message_tooltip . '" ' . ' href="' . $message_url . '" ' . ' style="color:#2b2b2b" ' . '>'
                . '<i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
                . '</a>';

            $edit_tooltip = $this->lang->line('tooltip_edit_text');
            $edit_url = base_url() . 'users/auth/edit_user/' . $a_user->id;
            $edit_anchor = '<a ' . ' title="' . $edit_tooltip . '" ' . ' href="' . $edit_url . '" ' . ' style="color:#2b2b2b" ' . '>'
                . '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
                . '</a>';

            $delete_tooltip = $this->lang->line('tooltip_delete_text');
            $delete_url = base_url() . 'users/auth/deleteUser/' . $a_user->id;
            $delete_anchor = '<a ' . ' title="' . $delete_tooltip . '" ' . ' href="' . $delete_url . '" ' . ' class="confirmation" ' . ' style="color:#2b2b2b" ' . '>'
                . '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">'
                . '</a>';

            $users[$i]->action = $view_anchor . '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $edit_anchor . '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $delete_anchor; //message is not defined yet
            /*action ends*/

            $i++;

        }
    }


    $json_data['draw'] = intval($requestData['draw']);
    /* $totalData: for every request/draw by clientside ,
     they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number,
     so we are sending same number in draw.*/
    $json_data['recordsTotal'] = intval($totalData); // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
    $json_data['recordsFiltered'] = intval($totalFiltered);

    //$users = $this->removeKeys($users); // converting to numeric indices.
    $json_data['data'] = $users;

    // checking requests in console.log() for testing starts;
    $json_data['last_query'] = $last_query;
    $json_data['common_filter_value'] = $common_filter_value;
    $json_data['specific_filters'] = $specific_filters;
    $json_data['order_column'] = $order['column'];
    $json_data['order_by'] = $order['by'];
    $json_data['limit_length'] = $limit['length'];
    $json_data['limit_start'] = $limit['start'];
    // checking requests in console.log() for testing ends;

    echo(json_encode($json_data));

}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var loading_image_src = '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + 'project_base_assets/base_demo_images/loading.gif';
    var loading_image = '<img src="' + loading_image_src + ' ">';
    var loading_span = '<span><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> ';
    var loading_text = "<div style='font-size:larger' ><?php echo lang('loading_text')?></div>";


    $('#user-table').DataTable({

        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        paging: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        lengthChange: true,
        searching: true,
        ordering: true,
        info: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        searchDelay: 500,
        infoEmpty:'<?php echo lang("no_user_found_text")?>',
        zeroRecords: '<?php echo lang("no_matching_user_found_text")?>',
        language: {
            processing: loading_image + '<br>' + loading_text
        },

        columns: [
            {data: "first_name"},
            {data: "last_name"},
            {data: "email"},
            {data: "groups"},
            {
                data: {
                    _: "act.html",
                    sort: "act.int"
                }
            },
            {
                data: {
                    _: "cr_on.display",
                    sort: "cr_on.timestamp"
                }
            },
            {
                data: {
                    _: "lt_lg_in.display",
                    sort: "lt_lg_in.timestamp"
                }
            },
            {data: "action"}

        ],

        columnDefs: [

            {
                'targets': 0,
                'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).attr('title', cellData);
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 1,
                'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).attr('title', cellData);
                }
            },

            {
                'targets': 2,
                'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).attr('title', cellData);
                }
            },

            {orderable: false, targets: [3, 7]} /*, { visible: false, targets: [3,5,6] }*/
        ],

        aaSorting: [[5, 'desc']],

        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'users/auth/get_users_by_ajax' ?>",                   // json datasource
            type: "post"

            //open succes only for test purpuses . remember when success is uncommented datble doesn't diplay data
            /*success: function (res) {

             console.log(res.last_query);
             console.log(res.common_filter_value);
             console.log(res.specific_filters);
             console.log(res.order_column);
             console.log(res.order_by);
             console.log(res.limit_start);
             console.log(res.limit_length);
             }*/
        }

    });
});
```